# Thread, QThread, how many per process is "reasonable"?

Tags: multithreading, qt, threadpool, qthread

**QUESTION:  How many "QThread" instances per process is "reasonable"?**

*(This specifically references Qt's `QThread` instance, but logically the question should relate to any thread-based design using any library.)*

For example, I understand that platform-specific resource limits may default to supporting up to thirty (30) "`QTcpSocket`" instances, so in theory, if you have thirty active-sockets, that would be thirty `QThread` instances when the system is under max-load.  However, that may not be a big deal, as most of those threads should be "sleeping/waiting" for network traffic.

Similarly, I would assume that one would instantiate UP TO the number of "cores" or "native-threads-can-execute" for `QThread` instances charged with "heavy-continuous-work".  So, if you had eight (8) cores, that might be another eight `QThread` instances (and these may be working all-the-time when the system is under max-load).

Then, of course, we have the "main-thread".

Does this then imply one would instantiate:

(30 socket-threads) + (8 worker-for-each-core) + (1 main thread)

...for 39 threads (on an 8-core system)?

Specifically, if application-specific needs had other thread-pool-needs, and you add a dozen-`QThread`-here and a dozen-`QThread`-instances-there, it seems like 100 `QThread` instances is kinda stupid, even if most of them are "idle/sleeping/waiting", right?

So, is there a cut-off?  "39-threads" is "reasonable", but "300-threads" is "unreasonable"?

(Yes, I understand there is a "default-stack-size-per-thread", such as "10MB-per-thread", so I am limited by virtual memory.  But, really, is it stupid to instantiate 30K threads -- it's a bad design that would ever want such a thing?)

Comment: I've often been cautioned against thread-per-connection type models in server or massively P2P code -- they don't scale very well.  (Each thread uses up quite a bit of memory, unless you tune things just so.)  For a client, it might not matter too much (since the number of things to watch is usually much smaller).  The answer depends almost entirely on the type of app you're making.  Know, though, that (at least in most threading implementations) one thread can watch a bunch of connections just fine, and pass the real work off to a pool of worker threads.

Comment: Depends.  Kaspersy has 166 threads on my box out of 1198 total.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QThread::idealThreadCount()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qthread.html#idealThreadCount) find out how many threads are likely to increase performance when all are busy. For threads that mostly wait, limit is OS-dependent, but for Qt, it's better to use the signal-slot system instead of very many threads. It's always lighter to have just an object with signals connected, than extra thread, especially if the extra thread has it's own event loop too. Most Qt network applications probably should not use threading at all.